# Do the Peculiars really think this character had a boat in 1943?

Tags: miss-peregrines-home

Disclaimer: I haven't read the books (yet). If it is explained in the book, please direct me to the book.

In Tim Burton's movie *Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children*, at 1:21:37,

> Barron kidnaps Miss Peregrine

and leaves.

Then there's a battle, and when it's over, the children regroup on the beach, at 1:27:10.
There's this dialogue:

> JAKE: Is there any sign of Barron and Miss Peregrine? 
>  OLIVE: Gone. Barron must have had a boat.

I don't understand why they are thinking that he may be still on the island (I suppose that those six minutes of screen time are at least an hour of in-universe time), or that he had a boat prepared *in 1943*.
It's more probable that he exited the loop and went back to <del>the future</del> 2016. If he had a boat, he had it in 2016, not in 1943.

### Do they really think that he had a boat in 1943? (Did he?)

Is this a movie error, a character error (after all, the Peculiar Children just had a very, very bad night) or am I missing something?